# highcharts.js and exporting.js version problem

Tags: ember.js, highcharts, export-to-pdf

I'm using highcharts v4.1.9. Currently, I'm in need of exporting highcharts in a pdf or whatever. The problem starts when I include exporting.js file on my website.

`exporting.src.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parts/Chart.js' of undefined`

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).iCheck is not a function`

These were the console error. I guessed this is due to version mismatch b/w highcharts.js and exporting.js (not sure though) so I tried looking for any lower version of exporting.js but no luck. please suggest a way to solve this without updating the highcharts version. Thank you in advance:)

Comment: Have you tried to attach the same version of the exporting module which you are using? `<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/4.1.9/modules/exporting.js"></script>` API: https://code.highcharts.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot:) now it is working fine!!

Comment: Could you help me with another question getSVGForLocalExport this function doesn't seem to be present in the older version of exporter.js. please give me a similar function in the older version for this. thank you:)

Comment: Highcharts doesn't provide and support newer functions in the older versions - that's why newer versions show up. You can try to implement it by yourself into your project base on: https://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.src.js